# How to pass variable to php to html?

Tags: php, html

I want to pass the php variable to html.
For this i create the code like this

```
<?php   
$neal="mynema";
 ?>
```

now i want this variable to pass into html for this i do like this

```
 <html>
<audio src="http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q="$neal"" Controls autoplay="autoplay">
</html>
```

bu it is not working how to do this in proper way???
i try this several time but i thinks that the url stings maing problem how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2):

You need:

1. To not put quotes in your HTML attribute values where they shouldn't be quotes
2. To write PHP to output the variable instead of HTML with `$neal` in it as literals

For best practise, run your variables through escaping functions to make them safe for URLs and then safe for HTML.

Such:

```
src="http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=<?php echo htmlspecialchars(urlencode($neal)); ?>"
```

In the, very unlikely, event that the quote marks should be part of the value. Include them in the original variable (and then let them get escaped) by the functions wrapped around it before the echo goes off.

```
$neal='"mynema"';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the short-open-tag `<?=` for echoing directly like this:

`<audio src="http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=<?= $neal ?>" Controls autoplay="autoplay">`

Though it is recommended to avoid this short-open-tags as they can be disabled in php.ini. Safest way is this syntax:

`<audio src="http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=<?php echo $neal; ?>" Controls autoplay="autoplay">`

Comment: `<?=` is not a short open tag in recent versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<audio src="http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=<?php echo $neal;?>" Controls autoplay="autoplay">
</html>
```

Comment: The value of your `src` attribute is `http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=`. That can't be right. Watch your quotes.

Comment: That's fixed, but is now an explanation-free game of spot-the-difference and doesn't follow best practise for escaping strings for inserting into URLs or HTML documents.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
$neal="mynema";
?>

<html>
<audio src="http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=<?php echo $neal ?>" Controls autoplay="autoplay">
</html>
```

Comment: The value of your `src` attribute is `http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=`. That can't be right. Watch your quotes.

Comment: @Quentin : Yep, forgot to take care of the quotes. Thank you :)

Comment: OP asked about to pass variable to HTML. Does it work on HTML file? I don't think so. Am I missing something?

Comment: @addicted20015 — That's fixed, but is now an explanation-free game of spot-the-difference and doesn't follow best practise for escaping strings for inserting into URLs or HTML documents.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan — PHP can (and, more often than not, does) output an HTML file

Comment: @Quentin Yes I know that. But I think OP mean to pass that to pure HTML. I guess

Comment: @KrishnaMohan — There is nothing in the question at all that even hints that the code is not being run through a PHP interpreter.